# Remove Jenkins Plugins via Script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Does anyone know how I can remove jenkins plugins from a script? I know there is no CLI command that exists for it. But was wondering, maybe you can just delete the plugin folder, and attempt to delete all associated data.

Reason I want this, is I want to develop a script that will run nightly. It will scan each Jenkins server, remove plugins if not found in file stored in GIT, it will add plugins if new ones are added, and upgrade or downgrade other plugins if the version doesn't match. The goal is to keep all Jenkins servers in sync as far as plugins go.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

groovy script for removing a plugin:

```
String pluginNameToRemove = "myPluginToRemove"
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def pluginManager = jenkins.getPluginManager()
def pluginWrapperToUninstall = pluginManager.getPlugin(pluginNameToRemove)
pluginWrapperToUninstall.doDoUninstall()
```

You can also remove the content of the plugins folder, download all the plugins you want according to the file, copy them to the plugins folder and restart jenkins. (We have a very similar flow on our environment for deploying jenkins instances)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: Does this work now. I get Null pointer exception. What should be the name of the plugin? I wanted to delete Ant plugin. I tried giving, Ant, Ant Plugin etc... nothing is working.